# Three.js ParametricGeometry animation (dynamically changing function)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am really new to computer graphics, and I started experimenting with some things with THREE.js. So I wanted to an animation of a flag (wave motions) and I couldn't find anything (maybe I don't know what to search). So I made my flag with a parametric geometry, and the function is just a cos. And I wan't to animate the flag by dynamically changing the function of the parametric geometry. How can I do that, and is this the correct way of doing this?

P.S. The change in the function that I want is simply moving the cos along the X asis so it looks like the flag is moving.

Answer (score 2):

In dependency on amount of vertices in your mesh, you can use shaders or simple changing of vertices in your animation loop with `cos` function.

Below, there's the approach with simple changing.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 2, 10 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( 10, 10 ) );

var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 3, 20, 3 );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "red", side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) );
scene.add( plane );

render();
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  planeGeom.vertices.forEach( v => {
    v.z = Math.cos( .5 * v.x - Date.now() * .001 ) * .5;
  });
  planeGeom.verticesNeedUpdate = true; // the most important thing, when you change vertices
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```